# Is it possible to click buttons in the toolbar with macros in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there anyway to make a macro that can click buttons in the tool bars of Excel? I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what buttons you are wanting to select? There are macros for this, but again it depends on the buttons you want to select.

Comment: They are buttons for an excel add on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can record a macro, which will capture your actions.

For Excel 2010:
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-record-a-macro-to-automate-tasks-in-excel-2.html

For Excel 2013:
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-record-new-macros-in-excel-2013.html

In your case, to take this even further, you can do ***[coded UI testing right from Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400217.aspx)***. For what you are trying to do, this is even better than only trying to automate a button-click to fire a custom add-in.

Comment: I was able to get that far with it, but what I'm looking for is something that will automatically click the buttons in the tool bar as well.

Comment: That doesn't make sense... if the macro performs the action, that is the click.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to create an automated test for an excel addon that involves some clicking in the top menu bar.

Comment: That helps. How about accessing your add-in through VBA? http://fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut08.htm

Comment: You can do coded UI testing right from Visual Studio using this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400217.aspx, which is even better than only trying to automate a button-click to fire a custom add-in.

Comment: @RobM, that link is dead, here is the wayback version of it, https://web.archive.org/web/20191022132719/http://fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut08.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way how you can achieve it with excel 2010:
File->Options->Quick Access Toolbar.
in the "Choose Commands From" list you click "Macros". Select the macro and click add.
If you want change the name of the button you can click "Modify".
Hope it will help you.